# PDOStatement::rowCount retorna -1

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Preciso saber quantos registros foram inseridos na query abaixo.

```
public function CadastraCliente() {
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
            INSERT INTO SISCli (CdInscricao,DsEntidade,DsApelido,InInscricao,InCadastro,DsEndereco,NrCEP,NrInscricaoEstadual,NrCGCCPF,NrTelefone,DtCadastro,CdEmpresa,DsEMail,DsUSuarioInc,InClassificacaoFiscal,DsBairro)
            SELECT
            right( ('00000000' + cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 14) as [CdInscricao],
            ESP353_XML.DES_DsEntidade AS [DsEntidade],
            ESP353_XML.DES_DsApelido AS [DsApelido],
            ESP353_XML.DES_InInscricao,
            0 AS [InCadastro],
            ESP353_XML.DES_DsEndereco AS [DsEndereco],
            ESP353_XML.DES_NrCEP AS [NrCEP],
            ESP353_XML.DES_NrInscricaoEstadual AS [NrInscricaoEstadual],
            case when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF) > 11
            then right( ('00'+ cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 14) 
            else right( ('00000'+ cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 11) 
                end as [NrCGCCPF],
            ESP353_XML.DES_NrTelefone AS [NrTelefone],
            GETDATE() AS [DtCadastro],
            case when SISCEP.DsUF='SP' then '4' 
            when SISCEP.DsUF='PR' then '3'
            when SISCEP.DsUF='SC' then '12'
            ELSE '1' END
            as [CdEmpresa], 
            ESP353_XML.DES_DsEMail as [DsEMail],
            'EdiXML' AS [DsUSuarioInc],
            ESP353_XML.DES_InClassificacaoFiscal,
            substring(ISNULL(ESP353_XML.DES_DsBairro,0),1,15) as [DES_DsBairro]
            FROM ESP353_XML
            LEFT JOIN SISCEP ON SISCEP.NrCep = ESP353_XML.DES_NrCEP
            where not exists (select 1 from SISCli A WHERE cast(A.CdInscricao as numeric) = cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as numeric))
            ");
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->conn->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->conn->rollback();
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

O que eu já tentei:

```
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
print_r($count);
```

Comment: Retorna sempre zero? qual é o problema do código?

Comment: já tentaste fazer `count()` ? O que `$stmt->rowCount();` retorna ?

Comment: Retorna -1 quando dou o `print_r` no `$count`

Comment: Você quer o numero de queries executadas ou o numero de UPDATEs e INSERTs executados?

Comment: De update's e insert's executados. Quantas linhas foram afetadas, o mesmo retorno que mostra ao executar diretamente no sgbd.

Comment: @Kevin.F tente executar o rowCount depois do commit e me diga o que aconteceu.

Comment: Continua retornando -1, depois que eu executo essa função chamo ela la na view, por isso queria mostrar quantos foram executados(no meu caso cadastrados).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione o atributo `array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)` como descrito na **documentação**:

> You would most commonly use this to set the PDO::ATTR_CURSOR value to PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL to request a scrollable cursor. Some drivers have driver specific options that may be set at prepare-time.

Tradução:

> Você pode normalmente usar isto para definir o PDO::ATTR_CURSOR com o valor PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL para solicitar um "ponteiro rolável". Alguns drivers tem opções que podem ser definidas no tempo de "preparação" (`prepare(...)`)

Um exemplo ficaria assim:

```
 $sql = "
        INSERT INTO SISCli (CdInscricao,DsEntidade,DsApelido,InInscricao,InCadastro,DsEndereco,NrCEP,NrInscricaoEstadual,NrCGCCPF,NrTelefone,DtCadastro,CdEmpresa,DsEMail,DsUSuarioInc,InClassificacaoFiscal,DsBairro)
        SELECT
        right( ('00000000' + cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 14) as [CdInscricao],
        ESP353_XML.DES_DsEntidade AS [DsEntidade],
        ESP353_XML.DES_DsApelido AS [DsApelido],
        ESP353_XML.DES_InInscricao,
        0 AS [InCadastro],
        ESP353_XML.DES_DsEndereco AS [DsEndereco],
        ESP353_XML.DES_NrCEP AS [NrCEP],
        ESP353_XML.DES_NrInscricaoEstadual AS [NrInscricaoEstadual],
        case when LEN(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF) > 11
        then right( ('00'+ cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 14) 
        else right( ('00000'+ cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as varchar)), 11) 
            end as [NrCGCCPF],
        ESP353_XML.DES_NrTelefone AS [NrTelefone],
        GETDATE() AS [DtCadastro],
        case when SISCEP.DsUF='SP' then '4' 
        when SISCEP.DsUF='PR' then '3'
        when SISCEP.DsUF='SC' then '12'
        ELSE '1' END
        as [CdEmpresa], 
        ESP353_XML.DES_DsEMail as [DsEMail],
        'EdiXML' AS [DsUSuarioInc],
        ESP353_XML.DES_InClassificacaoFiscal,
        substring(ISNULL(ESP353_XML.DES_DsBairro,0),1,15) as [DES_DsBairro]
        FROM ESP353_XML
        LEFT JOIN SISCEP ON SISCEP.NrCep = ESP353_XML.DES_NrCEP
        where not exists (select 1 from SISCli A WHERE cast(A.CdInscricao as numeric) = cast(ESP353_XML.DES_NrCGCCPF as numeric))
        ";

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
```

E troque:

```
 } catch (Exception $e) {
```

por:

```
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
```

Comment: Agora sim, o que faz esse atributo `array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)` ?

Comment: @Kevin.F é porque o PDO é uma classe usada para diferentes tipos de bancos e por padrão isto não vem configurado, então conforme o link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-parameters explica que geralmente é preciso configurar assim, mas se for outro tipo de banco talvez não seja necessário ou funcione diferente, não posso afirmar com precisão porque não conheço o source do PHP.

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com o seu comentário, você está recebendo -1 ao executar **$stmt->rowCount()**.

Isso indica, que a consulta - no seu caso um *INSERT* - foi inválida. O que isso significa? Provavelmente algum parâmetro (nome de uma coluna por exemplo) está incorreto.

Faça um teste, pegue o *statement* e execute direto no seu SGBD ou pelo terminal. Se retornar algum erro, é pelo motivo que expliquei acima. De qualquer forma, a formatação da sua *query* utilizando PDO está correta.

Faça o seguinte:

- Ao executar essa *query*, veja se os dados foram inseridos no banco de dados.
- Se a resposta for sim, execute o *rowCount* após o *commit*.
- Se a resposta for não, por favor, utilize `$this->conn->errorInfo()` para verificar se realmente há algum erro na sintaxe.

Comment: É estranho, pois já validei direto no sgbd e funcionou normal. E mesmo se me retornasse algo iria entra no `catch`.

Comment: @Kevin.F é provável que o sql tenha valores/syntax errado(a) já que a consulta é enorme isso aumenta a chance de erros

Comment: @13dev mas ae entraria na Exception não é? Creio que o problema talvez seja no commit e não na query (não tenho certeza).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não porque ele ta a capturar da classe `Exception`  e não de `PDOException`, (neste caso devia de capturar as 2),  @Kevin.F tenta capturar das duas classes

Comment: @13dev sim eu havia notado isto, como eu coloquei em minha resposta, todavia não estou bem certo do comportamento do PHP em try/catch, por isso disse que não tinha certeza

Comment: @Kevin.F Dá uma olhada na edição da resposta.

Comment: @Kevin.F Como não posso responder outros comentários pela falta de reputação... O motivo de utilizar o atributo `array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)` é porquê ele cria um cursor para a consulta, que permite que você iterar sobre o conjunto de resultados sem buscar todo o resultado de uma só vez... Para assim funcionar o `rowCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar as respostas já existentes vou dar um exemplo, como podes capturar as duas classes (`PDOException`,  `Exception`)  no mesmo **try**:

```
<?php
try {
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO minha_tabela (id, name, password)    VALUES (NULL, :name, :password)");
  $stmt->bindValue(":name", $_POST['name']);
  $stmt->bindValue(":password", $_POST['password']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  echo $count . " Utilizador adicionado com sucesso ";

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "DataBase Error: O utilizador não pode ser adicionado.<br>".$e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "General Error: O utilizador não pode ser adicionado.<br>".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Assim podes capturar `General` / `Database` erro, o que te vai ajudar bastante no *debug* do código.

Answer (score -1):

### Para PDO

Você pode utilizar o método `rowCount` que retorna o número de linhas afetadas pelo último `DELETE`, `INSERT` ou `UPDATE` executando pelo último objeto `PDOStatement`.

Definição:

```
public int PDOStatement::rowCount ( void )
```

Exemplo:

```
/* Exclui todos registros da tabela 'frutas' */
$del = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM frutas');
$del->execute();

/* Retorna o número de linhas que foram excluídas */
$count = $del->rowCount();
print("Excluídas $count linhas.\n");
```

### Para MySQLi

Você pode usar o método `affected-rows`do `mysqli`:

Definição:

```
int mysqli_affected_rows ( mysqli $link )
```

Exemplo:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE Language SET Status=1 WHERE Percentage > 50");
printf("Linhas afetadas (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: o autor tá a usar PDO

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo para PDO

Comment: mas mesmo assim não responde a pergunta do autor